# How do i solve with symbolic toolbox on matlab

Tags: matlab

im running with calculate and version is 2014b matlab tool 
But it has a problem on solve the equation

equation is as follows 
'exp(-(1-y)*x)*(-2+2*z^2)+exp(-2*(1-y)*x)*(1-z^2)+exp(-(1+y)*x)*(2-2*z^2-(4/2.5))+exp(-2*(1+y)*x)*(z^2-1)=-0.96'
and i want equation about 'x = ~~~(y,z)' 
then matlab commnets is 'Cannot find explicit solution'
plz want solving that problem. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that an explicit solution does exist at all?

Comment: exactly speaking, z is rinning form 0 to 1 and step is 0.02 ,   and y is running from 0 to 1 but with z 
 for example when z is 0 then y is running 0~1 (0.02) and z is 1 then y is running 0~1(0.02)